# "Tag not defined" for SecurityListRequest in quickfix

Tags: c++, quickfix

Trying to send SecurityListRequest in quickfix using the following code

```
void FixApplication::SendSecurityListRequest()
{
    FIX44::SecurityListRequest request(SecurityReqID(NextRequestID()), SecurityListRequestType(4));
    Session::sendToTarget(request, sessionID(false));
}
```

Getting

```
8=FIX.4.49=12435=334=349=nik52=20211015-19:40:29.47256=DERIBITSERVER57=U100D145=258=Tag appears more than once371=15372=y373=1310=011
```

in toAdmin function after the call to sendToTarget

**372=y** would mean issue is in MessageType "y" which is SecurityList **371=15** would mean issue in tag 15 which is Currency.

Can someone tell what is going wrong here ?

I also tried setting DataDictionary using settings.cfg but it results in

```
8=FIX.4.49=13435=334=349=nik52=20211015-19:46:29.29256=DERIBITSERVER57=U100D145=258=Tag not defined for this message type371=15372=y373=210=247
```

My current config file

```
[DEFAULT]
 
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=20
FILESTOREPATH=store
FileLogPath=Logs
StartDay=TUESDAY
StartTime=00:00:00
EndDay=TUESDAY
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUnorderedGroupFields=N
ValidateLengthAndChecksum=N
ReconnectInterval=60
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
SendResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ContinueInitializationOnError=Y
PrintIncoming=Y
PrintOutgoing=Y
PrintEvents=Y
IgnorePossDupResendRequests=Y
TargetSubID=U100D1
Username=
Password=
 
[SESSION]
SocketConnectHost=www.deribit.com
SocketConnectPort=9881
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=nik
TargetCompID=DERIBITSERVER
MDEntryType=Y
```

Comment: You haven't included enough info to say for sure, but you likely have a DataDictionary problem.  Look at the ACTUAL content of the message, and see if it matches the DD.   **ALSO:** "I also tried setting DataDictionary using settings.cfg" -- you _tried_ setting the DD?  Now I'm sure you have a DD config problem, because that's a noob thing to say (no offense).  I don't think you even know for sure what DD is actually being used when the app is running.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I included FIX44.xml from here github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/master/spec/FIX44.xml and yes I am really new to quickfix, still figuring things out. Can you suggest whats going wrong here ?

Comment: Post your config (minus any sensitive data).

Comment: https://ideone.com/3NNn7Q
Kindly find the link to my quickfix config file.

Comment: Just paste the config in your question.  I see you've used a bunch of `Validate*` settings; I suggest you remove those; they're usually hacks for people who don't know what they're doing.  Are you sure that the pathless "FIX44.xml" is correct relative to your binary's location?

Comment: Sure, I will do that and yes I am sure about the fact that pathless FIX44.xml is correct relative to the binary's location.

Comment: I also tried after removing all the Validate* settings from my config file and got the same result.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier do you think "FIX44.xml" is correct ? What can be potential issues for this failure ?